# Training custom object detection with TensorFlow lite for MLKit on iOS and Android: sample data characteristics and resultant capabilities

Tags: google-mlkit

My use case is the detection of checks (from a bank). I followed the MLKit docs to create a custom model that can detect the front and back of a check. It is working reasonably well, but I think it isn't quite good enough yet. I am finding it difficult to improve my understanding of some key concepts in the training process.

Which base model should I be using? I don't really understand the impact of the different base models. Should I be looking at any specific characteristics for my use case?

For the training data, should I be using cropped check images, or pictures of checks with the background still included?

I have 'check_front' and 'check_back' classifications working, but it would be great if I could also recognize an upside-down orientation. I tried training a model with sample data in both orientations, but the results were not satisfactory. I can figure out something else to determine the orientation, it would just be the cleanest/lightest if the object detection can handle it.

How many images does it take to make a good sample for something like this?

Comment: If you are using the object detection feature, it will detect the object first and only run the classifier on the cropped area of the object. In this case, cropped image as training data matches the use case better.

Comment: For detecting the orientation of the image, one work around is to use the ML Kit Text recognition API: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition/v2/android There is a getAngle API https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/mlkit/vision/text/Text.Line#getAngle()